# Is it okay to say just 'take' instead of 'take on' (as in 'take on your opponent')?

Tags: word-usage

> We can take them.

Is it grammatical? I haven't found this sense for 'take' in the Lexico dictionary. Does it mean it's a non-standard usage? I saw it.

Comment: "We can take them" means we can defeat them. "We can take them on" means we can fight  them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can take them on.

`to take something/someone on`/`to take on something/someone` means to accept and deal with a challenge. In this case, it means "We can fight them" or "We can accept their challenge.

> We can take them.

This actually means "We can defeat them". This can be used to show confidence when challenged by an opposing group. It can also mean "We can finish this challenge" though I don't hear it used like that much.

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/take Which sense do you mean? There's no such sense as "defeat"

Comment: You probably won't see it in dictionary entries for just the word ```take``` since it's colloquial speak, meaning it's kind of an idiomatic expression used in spoken English.

Answer (score 0):

> We can take them

is quite informal and also quite aggressive - more likely to be used to mean we can beat them in a physical fight. I would be careful of using it in any kind of formal situation (or if "they" might hear and you don't want a fight!).